# what to return if the data is not viewable in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Having a recyclerView with data feed list from backend. With display orientation change or some other condition some of the data item should not be displayed at that moment.

I guess it could return `Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` to identify this case:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) {
    return if (item(position).showConditionMeet() == false) {
               Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE
           } else {
             // normal case
               item(position).type 
           }
 }
```

but how to skip the creating view in the `override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)`

it cannot return null from there.  And if any view created then `override fun onBindViewHolder()` will be called as well.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getItemViewType(Int)` is fine.

`onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, Int)` should have a switch depending on viewType, where in case of `Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` you should simply return a BLANK view (View with height of 0 maybe?).

`onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, Int)` must also check viewType (you can simply call `ViewHolder.getItemViewType` on provided `ViewHolder`). In case of `Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` you know you have your BLANK view so skip binding then.

When your data is ready to display, call `notifyItemChanged(Int)` to tell adapter to refresh the relevant positions: it will call `getItemViewType(Int)` to determine what type of `ViewHolder` to use.

At this point your BLANK `ViewHolder` will be returned to `RecycledViewPool` and you should get your regular `ViewHolder` passed down to `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, Int)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your `getItemViewType`. Just make `getItemCount` return `0` if you don't want to render items.

```
override fun getItemCount() = if (hideItems) 0 else items.size
```

RecyclerView's adapter first checks how many items need to be inflated. If it returns 0, none of the other methods would be called.

Don't forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after setting the flag

Comment: Thanks @Sourabh! but there are some other items which are viewable, cant simply return 0 then